# QtCreator deploy step failed

Tags: qt, deployment, qt-creator, sftp, embedded-linux

In *QtCreator* when trying to deploy my application to Linux device I got following error:

```
15:38:56: Uploading file "/home/my_app_path/bin/arm/Release/*.*"...
15:38:56: Failed to upload file "/home/my_app_path/bin/arm/Release/*.*": Could not open for reading.
15:38:56: Deploy step failed.
Error while building/deploying project My_app_gui (kit: My kit)
When executing step "Upload files via SFTP"
```

I can connect to the device either from console using SSH or from *QtCreator* Devices dialog.From the message itself is not clear what can't be opened for reading.
Why is *QtCreator* not deploying my binaries to the target ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found out that *QtCreator* has some problems with **wild cards** when deploying files to the target. When I replace `*.*` with particular files in my `.pri` file everything works again.